# How to properly catch errors in axios get request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I use `openweathermap API` to get forecast. App is based on ReactJS and Redux. I have a problem with catch errors. I want to create alert for users when searched city doesn't exists in database. 
So, I have action like below:

```
export function fetchWeather (city) {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;
    const request = axios.get(url);

    return (dispatch) => {
        request
         .then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: data})
         })
         .catch((error) => { 
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR, payload: error})
        });
    };
```

And my reducer:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER, FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR } from '../actions/index';

export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
     console.log(action.payload) //I receive object, so it's ok
        return [...state, action.payload];

    case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
     console.log(action.payload) // I receive just info in console "Error: Request failed with status code 404"
        return state;
    }
    return state;
}
```

So, it works properly but I'm curious how to get proper object in error part to simple show alert with message info what happened wrong. Because when I check in inspector tab (Networks) there is nice object in response: 
`{cod: "404", message: "city not found"}`, but in `console.log(action.payload)` I have just info, no object, array... Why are these things different? How to get proper value of error response to show error message?

Comment: When you catch it you won't get the json that's been sent (you can inspect the error and see if there is anything there). If the request comes back normally (not go into catch) even though city does not exist then the json you get doesn't have a `data` member (only cod and message)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the API will always return 200 (success) when the connection works even though there is a 401 not allowed or 404 not found. Check out the following url in your dev tools network tab:

```
http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=nomatterNoApiKey
```

So anything going into catch is actual network problem.

```
request
.then((response) => {
  if(response.cod===200){
    dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: response.data});
  }else{
    dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR, payload: response.message});
  }
})
```

You have to make sure that is the correct way to use the API and still have to deal with network errors.